# Is it possible to make my WAMP server connectable outside of my LAN?

Tags: wamp, wampserver

Is it possible to make my WAMP server connectable outside of my LAN? Is it possible to host my own website for free and make it connectable from anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
You should point a domain to your external ip - find that entering google myip - example https://www.whatismyip-address.com/?check
On your DNS manager point your domain to your ip
On your router - if you have access you can forward all traffic on port 80 and 443 to your internal computer - which you can find using ipconfig /all (windows) or ifconfig (unix/osx) commands in CMD (windows) or Terminal (osx)
This works if you have a static ip (your isp will not change your ip)
If you can't change the port forwarding on the router from your isp you shoul ask them to put in bridge mode and you buy another router which will make all the dhcp and routing services.

Or you can use your router dns dynamic tools like no-ip.com or something similar to tell your changed address
and you will point your cname record to some domain like mydomain.no-ip.com

Or you can use https://ngrok.com/ which will expose your website on their domain

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by disabling the firewall for port 80.

Go to Search on right side of windows.
search "firewall".
open the "firewall with advanced".
go to inbound rules.
click on "new rule".
select the "Port" option.
click "next"
select "TCP" option.
select "Specific local ports:".
type "80" in next text box
click next.
select the "Allow the connection".
click "next".
click "next".
give the name "Port 80 Allow Rule".
click "next".

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], and read [answer].